# Why the standard deviation of discrete random variable is not divided by n?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

The standard deviation formula actually makes sense to me.

$\sqrt(\frac1N\sum(x-u)^2)$

However, I do not understand why in the standard deviation of a discrete random variable formula

$\sqrt( \sum(x-u)^2p)$

the $\frac1N$ does not appear.
Why it does not? 
What could be a graphical interpretation to understand the formula?

Comment: Your first formula for standard deviation is for a relatively limited set of applications, one of which is a discrete random variable with uniform probability. The "standard deviation" that is probably most often used in statistics, namely the sample standard deviation, has $N - 1$ in the denominator rather than $N.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the discrete random variable is uniform over $N$ values, then the probability $p$ associated with each value $x$ that it takes is $1/N$, and you recover the standard deviation formula that makes sense to you.

More generally, random variables will not be uniform, so you replace $1/N$ with different probabilities $p$ associated with each $x$. This is the second expression in your post.